# Remove last digit from all data in column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Just asking if this is possible:

I have a mysql database 'data' and a column 'count' which contains numbers such as

3741 
49215 
345 
4686794

I was wondering if there is a possibility to remove the last figure from each number in this column, so there will be these values:

374 
4921 
34 
468679

(for 100,000 rows so i can't do it manually :) )

Thank you!

Comment: you can use an update on that column, setting its value to the value it has but converting that value to a string, substringing to len-2 and converting to number again.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column? `int`? `varchar`?

Comment: Instead of working with strings you could also divide the number by 10 and then round it to the next lowest integer.

Comment: How about Floor(x/10)

Answer (score 1):

This will work if the field is numeric or string and is always > 0:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `count` = FLOOR(`count`/10)
```

Note single digit values will become 0

If some numbers are negative, it will not give the right answer and a substring approach like the other answers is better.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MySQL SUBSTRING function to extract portion of a string. Use CHAR_LENGTH function to calculate the number of characters in the string.

```
SELECT 
col,
SUBSTRING(col, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(col) - 1) AS col_trimme
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

is the data type is string you can

```
update my_table 
set my_column  = substr(my_column, 1, length(my_column) -2)
```

if is an int you can cast

```
update my_table 
set my_column  = cast(substr(cats(my_column AS varchar(16)), 1, length(my_column AS varchar(16)) -1), AS INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if the field is numeric or string:

```
UPDATE table SET count = SUBSTRING(count, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(count) - 1);
```